# Overwrite resource partially

Tags: android, android-styles

I am looking for a way to overwrite a style only partially:

In values\styles.xml

```
<style name="TitleBarTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>
```

In v16\styles.xml

```
<style name="TitleBarTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bilbo_swash_caps</item>
</style>
```

However I want it to take the textColor from the more general rule in both cases. Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it as follows:

`values\styles.xml`:

```
<style name="BaseTitleBarTextAppearance" parent="android:TextAppearance">
    <item name="android:textColor">@color/colorAccent</item>
</style>

<style name="TitleBarTextAppearance" parent="BaseTitleBarTextAppearance"/>
```

in your `v16\styles.xml`:

```
<style name="TitleBarTextAppearance" parent="BaseTitleBarTextAppearance">
    <item name="android:fontFamily">@font/bilbo_swash_caps</item>
</style>
```